# How to graph categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Example data:

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~Item, ~Description,
   123L, "something1",
   123L, "something1",
   123L, "something1",
   321L, "something2",
   321L, "something2",
   321L, "something2"
  )
```

I am trying to graph on x axis the unique descriptions, in this case a separate bar for something1 and something2

And on y axis the count of unique items, in this case bar for both of them should be at one as they each have one item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
tibble::tribble(
  ~Item, ~Description,
  123L, "something1",
  123L, "something1",
  123L, "something1",
  321L, "something2",
  321L, "something2",
  321L, "something2"
) %>%
  group_by(Description) %>%
  mutate(count = n_distinct(Item)/length(Item)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Description, y = count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>